# Apache won't serve new files even after restarting

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu-14.04, kohana-3.3

I've deployed some PHP files to the server, but I'm getting a 404 when trying to access them from the browser. Can someone explain to me when apache2 wouldn't serve new files?

Everything works perfectly in my local test environment, so I know the framework and the code works. Permissions are consistent with everything else. I've also done this a couple of weeks ago and it worked just like it is supposed to. Restarting apache does nothing, and redeploying also does nothing. I prefer not to restart the device itself. Anyone experience this before?

Comment: Could you take a look into the error log of Apache? Commonly located at `/var/log/apach2/error.log`.  it might give some help to your problem

Comment: @Ferrybig just tells me the request returned a 404 :/

Comment: Do you serve files directly or through Kohana?

Comment: @bato3 Through Kohana. Sorry, I forgot to answer this when I found out the issue was with the routing.